# How to remove Linux completely from my Acer Chromebook and reinstall

Tags: linux

I installed Linux a few days ago and there were some issues with some packages not being installed that caused some problems, I have tried fixing the issues in several ways but nothing has worked so I want to just remove Linux and reinstall it but I can't figure out how to do that. The only thing I have been able to find is to have a copy of Chrome OS on a flash drive and completely wipe my computer but I would prefer not to do that. Is there a way to remove Linux so I can go back and install it over again?

Comment: It would be more sensible understanding what happened with the packages. If you installed it once, why complicating and not just reinstalling it again? Have you tried reinstalling to see what it happens?

Comment: I didn't know I could just reinstall without removing it from my computer, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just format the corresponding filesystems. If your non-Chrome OS Linux root filesystem was EXT4 then you simply use mkfs.ext4 and that's it but usually installers take care of this task for you. This brings us to the most important question here: which Linux did you install and how? If you used https://chrx.org/ you just run it again with the parameters you need and it will take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't know that I could just reinstall without removing it first, I did use chrx so I was able to just run it again and it fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to delete the Linux partitions, you can do so with a USB stick. Since you've installed Linux before, you probably know how to boot from a flash drive. If there's a grub menu, select the option that's closest to Live Boot. Once you're in, you should be able to use an application such as parted, gparted, or cfdisk (I'm not sure which program comes with the distro you're running) to erase your Linux partitions.

Comment: That could be dangerous since chromebooks use a modified version of GPT as far as I know https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/cgpt